# how to execute sudo su --login username command with TRAMP

Tags: tramp, ssh, sudo

I have this weird setup that once I log onto our server with the `sudo uat` command, I will be logged in with my own user `dadinn@uat`. I have set up `.ssh/config` so that `uat` is really an alias for hostname `uat.foobar.com`.

To access some log files, I would first have to switch to user `app01@uat`.
Then once switched user, I would like to open file `~/logs/myapp/20221108.log`.

Under normal circumstances I would expect opening path `/ssh:uat|sudo:app01@:logs/myapp/20221108.log` with [TRAMP](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) would do the trick.

Unfortunately, because of our weird system setup, I can only access this file in the terminal with the following commands:

```
dadinn@dev:~$ ssh uat
dadinn@uat password: ********
dadinn@uat:$ sudo su - app01
[sudo] password for dadinn: ********
app01@uat:~$ cat logs/myapp/20221108.log
```

An irrelevant detail is that for SSH login I have to use a password instead of public key. Nevertheless, I don't think that affects this issue.

Also, I have to note that once I've ssh-d into the uat host, I **MUST** use the command `sudo su - app01` to switch user.

Typing `sudo su app01` throws an error:

`Sorry, user dadinn is not allowed to execute '/sr/bin/su app01' as root on uat.foobar.com`

Also, typing `sudo -i -u app01` throws an error:

`Sorry, user dadinn is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as app01 on uat.foobar.com`

Following suggestions in the comments, the output of `sudo -l` shows that indeed there are explicit limitations on what commands my user can execute with sudo:

```
User dadinn may run the following commands on uat: 
  (root) /bin/su - app01, /bin/su - app02
```

I have tried connecting with TRAMP using `/ssh:uat|sudo:|su:app01@:` and pressed TAB, which did start to ask for sudo password, but then failed with this error in the mini-buffer:

`[Tramp: Opening connection for app01@uat using su...failed]`

I assume this might be because TRAMP doesn't pass the --login option to the su command?

Any suggestions how to work around this?

Comment: What does `sudo -u app01` do? `sudo su - app01` uses `sudo` to become root, then runs `su` to become another user, which is a commonly–seen anti–pattern. I suppose it is possible that your system administrator has deliberately configured `sudo` so that you are only allowed to use it to run `su`, but that seems unlikely. Incidentally, `sudo -i app01` is an error because it is trying to login as root and run the command `app01`. `sudo -i -u app01` should do what you want though. I suppose you could also include the output to `sudo -l` in your question as an aide to debugging.

Comment: `sudo -u app01` does nothing, except it seems to print out lines from the usage help (only the lines starting with `usage: `). I also think it seems quite the case that the administrators indeed deliberately configured `sudo` to only allow executing `su`. I can see my mistake with the `sudo -i app01` command. `sudo -i -u app01` on the other hand throws error `Sorry, user dadinn is not allowed to execute '/bin/bash' as app01 on uat.foobar.com`.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting trying `sudo -l`, it indeed explains the situation:
`User dadinn may run the following commands on uat: (root) /bin/su - app01, /bin/su - app02`. So the admins deliberately limited what commands can be executed.

Comment: Wow, that is weird. Well, if using both the `sudo` and `su` tramp methods doesn’t work, then there’s nothing for it but to add a new method to `tramp-methods` as suggested.

Answer (score 4):

The variable `tramp-methods` keeps the arguments which Tramp uses for different methods. For `sudo`, there is the entry

```
`("sudo"
  (tramp-login-program        "env")
  (tramp-login-args           (("SUDO_PROMPT=P\"\"a\"\"s\"\"s\"\"w\"\"o\"\"r\"\"d\"\":")
                               ("sudo") ("-u" "%u") ("-s") ("-H") ("%l")))
  (tramp-remote-shell         ,tramp-default-remote-shell)
  (tramp-remote-shell-login   ("-l"))
  (tramp-remote-shell-args    ("-c"))
  (tramp-connection-timeout   10)
  (tramp-session-timeout      300)
  (tramp-password-previous-hop t))
```

See tramp-sh.el for details. I recommend you add an own method, let's call it `mysudo`, with the same specification as above, but with changed `tramp-login-args`.

Comment: This looks quite promising. Looking at the `"su"` method `(tramp-login-args (("-") ("%u")))` option is already set. I don't understand why `/ssh:uat|sudo:|su:app01@:` does not work. I assume this would execute the `sudo su - app01` command on the remote host. I also see that both `"su"` and `"sudo"` methods have a `(tramp-remote-shell #1#)` option... I can't find any documentation on what that `#1#` means.

Comment: Sorry, just realised that `/ssh:uat|sudo:|su:app01@:` would not execute `sudo su - app01`, but possibly instead `sudo bash -c su - app01`, which is not a sudo command the policy would allow.